# Ionic/Angular 5.0.1 global.scss commented out,, how do I apply to my app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am following this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2ga-iXS5i4) and I am at point 3:06:35

When I apply the css utility `text-center` on the `<h1>` tag however,
my header does not get centered in the app.

When I ctrl + f this css utility on chrome's inspector, it seems that this css utility is part of `global.scss` file. However when I `ionic serve`, all the contents of this file is commented out.
[image]

Looking at the source code, I never commented any of it
[image]

How do I apply global.scss scripts in my ionic app?

Comment: which is your ionic version? ionic 4 and greater use class="ion-text-center" to center the content

Comment: Hi @parrycima, unfortunately that script did not do anything.. my `<h1>` tag remains uncentered

Comment: There is any error inside console tab when you inspect your page via chrome?

Comment: @parrycima just two warnings: `ative: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator` and `ative: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator`

Comment: do you have any git repo? my username is parrycima.

Comment: @parrycima hi, here it is https://github.com/MalkyTheKid/malcIonicBuildDemo thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case, you are giving `text-center` to the `ion-label` element

Change your code from this:

```
<h1><ion-label text-center class="ion-text-center">{{ loadedRecipe.title }} Ingredients</ion-label></h1>
```

to:

```
 <h1 class="ion-text-center"><ion-label>{{ loadedRecipe.title }} Ingredients</ion-label></h1>
```

Comment: I see,  `<h1 class="ion-text-center">` tag does work but the tutorial's `<h1 text-center>` does not.. is it because of my Ionic version?

Comment: anyway, accepting this answer. More css utilities here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities

Comment: It's because of Ionic version!